# fr:number breaks after two iterations of repeatable grid in Orbeon 4.0.1

Tags: orbeon

I've been trying to work out why fr:number field breaks in repeating grids. First two rows function fine but from the third row onwards no change events are sent, the value is not saved to fr-form-instance and formatting is not done to the value. I've been searching if someone else has had this problem but I haven't found any mention of this problem what so ever and have not been able to pinpoint the cause of this problem.

So my question: Does someone know if this was a known problem in 4.0.1 and if yes then can it be fixed or circumvented in some way without updating Orbeon?

Our company is using Orbeon 4.0.1 and apparently it's too costly in work hours to update because of some company specific modifications done so update is not an answer I can really use.

Answer (score 0):

You're unlikely to get much help in the community for issues that have been fixed in newer versions. So, I would recommend you first try to reproduce the problem with the latest release (4.10 at the time of this writing).

- If you do reproduce it, post about it on [Orbeon Forms forum](http://discuss.orbeon.com/) (Stack Overflow isn't really for bug reports).
- If you don't reproduce it, i.e. if the problem has been fixed, it will be to you to weigh the cost of upgrading to 4.10 vs. the cost of getting support from Orbeon through a [PE subscription](http://www.orbeon.com/pricing).